# Error with if/elif statements and turtle commands

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been having an odd error with if/else statements. For some reason, when I use this code (intro project to turtle graphics)

```
from turtle import *
print('Hello. I am Terry the Turtle. Enter a command to make me draw a line, or ask for help.')
on = True
shape('turtle')
if on == True:
   c1 = str(input('Enter command: ')
   if c1 == 'forward':
      c2 = eval(input('How many degrees? ' ))
      right(c2)
   elif c1 == 'right':
      c2 = eval(input('How many degrees? ' ))
      right(c2)
   elif c1 == 'left':
      c2 = eval(input('How many degrees? ' ))
      left(c2)
   elif c1 == 'goodbye':
      print('Bye!')
      on = False
   else:
      print('Possible commands: forward, right, left, goodbye.')
```

For some odd reason, the `if` and `elif` statements keep returning syntax errors, yet they do not seem to have any visible errors. I tried doing similar things, but it kept on returning syntax errors. Is there any way to fix this?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, this is my first time here and I am just really confused.

Comment: Why are you using `eval(input())`?

Comment: Anyways, typo... `str(input('Enter command: ')` <--- Missing close paren

Comment: I'm assuming it's an attempt at type conversion. OP should be using `int(input())` instead, if that's the case.

Comment: Please post an actual error message. Are you sure it's the `if`/`elif` statements and not `eval`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
from turtle import *
print('Hello. I am Terry the Turtle. Enter a command to make me draw a line, or ask for help.')
on = True
shape('turtle')
# Get commands until user enters goodbye
while on:
    c1 = str(input('Enter command: '))
    if c1 == 'forward':
        # Ask how far when moving
        c2 = int(input('How far? '))
        # Use forward to move
        forward(c2)
    elif c1 == 'right':
        c2 = int(input('How many degrees? '))
        right(c2)
    elif c1 == 'left':
        c2 = int(input('How many degrees? '))
        left(c2)
    elif c1 == 'goodbye':
        print('Bye!')
        on = False
    else:
        print('Possible commands: forward, right, left, goodbye.')
```

This should be run with Python3 (e.g. `python3 myrtle.py`).

Comment: What did you change, what was wrong? The only thing I've spotted at a glance is `while on:`.

Comment: I fixed the indentation, but the OP also fixed that. I changed the `eval` to `int`, but that should not have made a difference if the OP was entering numbers. The statement by the OP about "statements keep returning syntax errors" seemed fishy, so I just wanted to prove that the script didn't actually have syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

For c1, you don't have to indicate it is a string as inputs are already strings
And no need for "eval".

Try:

```
from turtle import *
print('Hello. I am Terry the Turtle. Enter a command to make me draw a line, or ask for help.')
on = True
shape('turtle')
while on == True:
   c1 = input('Enter command: ')
   if c1 == 'forward':
      c2 = int(input('How far forward? ' ))
      forward(c2)
   elif c1 == 'right':
      c2 = int(input('How many degrees? ' ))
      right(c2)
   elif c1 == 'left':
      c2 = int(input('How many degrees? ' ))
      left(c2)
   elif c1 == 'goodbye':
      print('Bye!')
      on = False
   else:
      print('Possible commands: forward, right, left, goodbye.')
```